# Multiple Nested Dictionaries into Dataframe as one single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested, concatenation

I am working on a nested dictionary and not able to put it in a dataframe.

This is what it looks like:

```
{'props': {'initialProps': {'statusCode': 0, '$isMobile': False, '$isIOS': None, '$isAndroid': False, '$host': 'www.tiktok.com', '$pageUrl': '/@alanwalkermusic/video/6816594007829859589', '$language': 'en', '$originalLanguage': 'en', '$languageList': [{'value': 'id', 'alias': 'id-ID', 'label': 'Bahasa Indonesia', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'de', 'alias': 'de-DE', 'label': 'Deutsch', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'en', 'alias': 'en', 'label': 'English', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'es', 'alias': 'es', 'label': 'Español', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'fr', 'alias': 'fr', 'label': 'Français', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'it', 'alias': 'it-IT', 'label': 'Italiano', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'pl', 'alias': 'pl-PL', 'label': 'Polski', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'pt_BR', 'alias': 'pt-BR', 'label': 'Português', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'vi', 'alias': 'vi-VN', 'label': 'Tiếng Việt', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'tr', 'alias': 'tr-TR', 'label': 'Türkçe', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ru', 'alias': 'ru-RU', 'label': 'Русский', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'hi', 'alias': 'hi-IN', 'label': 'हिन्दी', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ko', 'alias': 'ko-KR', 'label': '한국어', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ja', 'alias': 'ja-JP', 'label': '日本語', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'zh_Hant', 'alias': 'zh-Hant-TW', 'label': '繁體中文', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ar', 'alias': 'ar', 'label': 'العربية', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}], '$region': 'DE', '$appId': 1233, '$os': 'windows', '$baseURL': 'm.tiktok.com', '$downloadLink': {'amazon': {'visible': True, 'normal': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0117U0G3M/'}, 'google': {'visible': True, 'normal': 'https://www.tiktok.com/download-link/af/com.zhiliaoapp.musically'}, 'apple': {'visible': True, 'normal': 'https://www.tiktok.com/download-link/af/id835599320'}}, '$abTestVersion': {'clientParameters': '{}', 'clientVersionName': '', 'versionName': '1618717', 'parameters': '{}', 'startTime': '', 'endTime': ''}, '$appType': 'm', '$gray': {'upload': False, 'tea': False}, '$reflowType': 't', '$legalList': [{'title': 'TikTok.com Cookies Policy', 'key': 'tiktok-website-cookies-policy', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/tiktok-website-cookies-policy?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Open Source', 'key': 'open-source', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/open-source?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Virtual Items', 'key': 'virtual-items', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/virtual-items?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Intellectual Property Policy', 'key': 'copyright-policy', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/copyright-policy?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Law Enforcement', 'key': 'law-enforcement', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/law-enforcement?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Privacy Policy', 'key': 'privacy-policy', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/privacy-policy?lang=en'}, {'title': 'Terms of Service', 'key': 'terms-of-use', 'href': 'https://www.tiktok.com/legal/terms-of-use?lang=en'}], '$botType': 'others', '$config': {'covidBanner': {'open': True, 'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com/safety/resources/covid-19', 'background': 'rgba(125,136,227,1)'}}, '$wid': '6819614602332063233'}, 'pageProps': {'serverCode': 200, 'pageState': {'regionAppId': 1233, 'os': 'windows', 'region': 'DE', 'baseURL': 'm.tiktok.com', 'appType': 't', 'fullUrl': 'https://www.tiktok.com/node/share/video/@alanwalkermusic/6816594007829859589'}, 'videoData': {'itemInfos': {'id': '6816594007829859589', 'video': {'urls': ['https://v19.muscdn.com/afefda4362dccd13b93a4d8e79ab5338/5ea477c7/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/7f922f16b9534b80be6523cbb8ba2ce2/?a=1233&br=2652&bt=1326&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=202004251147400101150770371E5160EE&lr=tiktok_m&qs=0&rc=MzY3cXc1OjxwdDMzNjczM0ApNDtnNTY1Ojw2N2k8NDU4ZWdoZXBmLjE0ZGBfLS0vMTZzczZjYDEvL2BgMDAzXy0uMC86Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr='], 'videoMeta': {'width': 540, 'height': 960, 'ratio': 11, 'duration': 11}}, 'covers': ['https://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/8187e5fe9a0f684529910363f5dbe428'], 'authorId': '84453035275386880', 'coversOrigin': ['https://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/7dd18717d8aa4916abc5699c25c09b3e_1587111976'], 'text': 'I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'commentCount': 300, 'diggCount': 14145, 'playCount': 91447, 'shareCount': 29, 'createTime': '1587111974', 'isActivityItem': False, 'warnInfo': [], 'liked': False, 'commentStatus': 0, 'showNotPass': False}, 'authorInfos': {'verified': True, 'secUid': 'MS4wLjABAAAAhS4j-WG_Zq5WJfdV35QEqorNPzc_kkFVNPQmGM6mQIWEg6FOgjS-Dl9eISlYvPDc', 'uniqueId': 'alanwalkermusic', 'userId': '84453035275386880', 'nickName': 'Alan Walker', 'covers': ['https://p16.muscdn.com/img/musically-maliva-obj/1649466056705029~c5_100x100.jpeg']}, 'musicInfos': {'musicId': '6805465027164768258', 'musicName': 'Heading Home', 'authorName': 'Alan Walker, Ruben', 'covers': ['https://p16.muscdn.com/img/musically-maliva-obj/1649466056705029~c5_100x100.jpeg']}, 'authorStats': {'followerCount': 2147815, 'heartCount': '10903873'}, 'challengeInfoList': [], 'duetInfo': '0', 'textExtra': []}, 'shareUser': {'secUid': '', 'userId': '', 'uniqueId': '', 'nickName': '', 'signature': '', 'covers': [], 'coversMedium': [], 'coversLarger': [], 'isSecret': False}, 'shareMeta': {'title': 'Alan Walker on TikTok', 'desc': 'I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'image': {'url': 'http://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/img/tos-maliva-p-0068/8187e5fe9a0f684529910363f5dbe428~tplv-tiktok-play.image', 'width': 540, 'height': 960}}, 'statusCode': 0, 'langList': [{'value': 'id', 'alias': 'id-ID', 'label': 'Bahasa Indonesia', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'de', 'alias': 'de-DE', 'label': 'Deutsch', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'en', 'alias': 'en', 'label': 'English', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'es', 'alias': 'es', 'label': 'Español', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'fr', 'alias': 'fr', 'label': 'Français', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'it', 'alias': 'it-IT', 'label': 'Italiano', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'pl', 'alias': 'pl-PL', 'label': 'Polski', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'pt_BR', 'alias': 'pt-BR', 'label': 'Português', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'vi', 'alias': 'vi-VN', 'label': 'Tiếng Việt', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'tr', 'alias': 'tr-TR', 'label': 'Türkçe', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ru', 'alias': 'ru-RU', 'label': 'Русский', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'hi', 'alias': 'hi-IN', 'label': 'हिन्दी', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ko', 'alias': 'ko-KR', 'label': '한국어', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ja', 'alias': 'ja-JP', 'label': '日本語', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'zh_Hant', 'alias': 'zh-Hant-TW', 'label': '繁體中文', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}, {'value': 'ar', 'alias': 'ar', 'label': 'العربية', 'children': [{'value': 'default', 'label': ''}]}], 'webId': '6819614602168567298', 'requestId': '23892479587815260433', 'videoObjectPageProps': {'videoProps': {'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@alanwalkermusic/video/6816594007829859589', 'name': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) on TikTok I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'description': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) has created a short video on TikTok with music Heading Home. I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'keywords': 'alanwalkermusic, Alan Walker,', 'thumbnailUrl': ['https://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/8187e5fe9a0f684529910363f5dbe428', 'https://p16-va-default.akamaized.net/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/7dd18717d8aa4916abc5699c25c09b3e_1587111976'], 'uploadDate': '2020-04-17T08:26:14.000Z', 'contentUrl': 'https://v19.muscdn.com/afefda4362dccd13b93a4d8e79ab5338/5ea477c7/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/7f922f16b9534b80be6523cbb8ba2ce2/?a=1233&br=2652&bt=1326&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=202004251147400101150770371E5160EE&lr=tiktok_m&qs=0&rc=MzY3cXc1OjxwdDMzNjczM0ApNDtnNTY1Ojw2N2k8NDU4ZWdoZXBmLjE0ZGBfLS0vMTZzczZjYDEvL2BgMDAzXy0uMC86Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=', 'embedUrl': 'https://www.tiktok.com/embed/v2/6816594007829859589', 'commentCount': '300', 'duration': 'PT11S', 'audio': {'name': 'Heading Home - Alan Walker, Ruben', 'author': 'Alan Walker, Ruben', 'mainEntityOfPage': {'@type': 'ItemPage', '@id': 'https://www.tiktok.com/music/Heading-Home-6805465027164768258'}}, 'creator': {'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'Alan Walker', 'alternateName': 'alanwalkermusic', 'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@alanwalkermusic', 'interactionStatistic': [{'@type': 'InteractionCounter', 'interactionType': {'@type': 'http://schema.org/LikeAction'}, 'userInteractionCount': '10903873'}, {'@type': 'InteractionCounter', 'interactionType': {'@type': 'http://schema.org/FollowAction'}, 'userInteractionCount': 2147815}]}, 'width': 540, 'height': 960, 'interactionStatistic': [{'@type': 'InteractionCounter', 'interactionType': {'@type': 'http://schema.org/WatchAction'}, 'userInteractionCount': 91447}, {'@type': 'InteractionCounter', 'interactionType': {'@type': 'http://schema.org/LikeAction'}, 'userInteractionCount': 14145}, {'@type': 'InteractionCounter', 'interactionType': {'@type': 'http://schema.org/ShareAction'}, 'userInteractionCount': 29}]}, 'pageProps': {'type': 'ItemPage', 'id': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@alanwalkermusic/video/6816594007829859589'}, 'breadcrumbProps': {'urlList': [{'name': 'TikTok', 'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com'}, {'name': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) Official | TikTok', 'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@alanwalkermusic'}, {'name': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) on TikTok I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'url': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@alanwalkermusic/video/6816594007829859589'}]}}, 'metaParams': {'title': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) on TikTok I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'keywords': 'alanwalkermusic, Alan Walker,', 'description': 'Alan Walker(@alanwalkermusic) has created a short video on TikTok with music Heading Home. I’m that friend who can’t stand still when taking photos', 'robotsContent': 'index, follow'}, 'isSSR': True, 'pageOptions': {'header': {'showUpload': True, 'type': 'webapp'}, 'headOptions': None}}, 'pathname': '/share/video'}, 'page': '/share/video', 'query': {'uniqueId': 'alanwalkermusic', 'id': '6816594007829859589', '$initialProps': {'$wid': '6819614602332063233'}, 'webtoken': 'tac=\'i+2gv2ay5eehis!i#piis"yZl!%s"l"u&kLs#l l#vr*charCodeAtx0[!cb^i$1em7b*0d#>>>s j\\uffeel  s#0y\\xe8g,&qnfme|ms l vk.}l ,(dfijxdaamvk5}l ,(dfijxdaam,$lwcamk\\xadl ,(dfijxdaam,$lwcams!l!v,\\\'nfmosCkmx,*~bgyad>r}~[!c0b<k$t jql!v,\\\'nfmosCkmx,%cokm3[!c0d#===k$t jMl!v,\\\'nfmosCkmx,0xefc.:9&*.4+2-0.[!c0d#===k"t f z[ cb|1d<y\\u01ea,(|fY\\x7f~d`hs g,(lfi~ah`{ms!g,&qnfme|ms"g,)gk}ejo{\\x7fcms#,)|doikgauus$ul"d\\\',typeofl$d#===v!kA}l"vl mx[ c,/T\\x7fsxvwa6@qw~tk@d#!==v!k\\\\}gr&Object,)yxdxbzv`tml mvr$callxl"[!c,/T\\x7fsxvwa6@qw~tk@d#!==v!k4}ul!d\\\',typeofl$d#===v!kG}l!vl mx[ cv,\\\'nfmosCkmx,(Lfi~ah`{[!c0b<v!k4}ul#d\\\',typeofl$d#===v!kD}l#vl mx[ c,2I|v\\x7fstl9Tzjty~TNP~d#!==v!k=}ugr(locationd\\\',typeofl$d#===k"t fv!k4}l!,,hbmz}t|gYzrrm!!!kjg,\\\'oaz~d~tms%ul%d\\\',typeofl$d#===v!kB}l%vl mx[ c,0K~pyqvb7PpiosogBd#!==k"t f z[ cb|1d<y\\xe2g,&qnfme|ms l vk-}l ,\\\'dggyd`hmvk7}l ,\\\'dggyd`hm,\\\'aa{oiyjmk"t ugr.InstallTriggerd\\\',typeof,)|doikgauud#!==kwl vkn}l ,*e~xh|Xyuf{ml ,*cebh|Xyuf{mb-\\x94b>v!kF}l ,+dyyk}Xt{t|aml ,+bbck}Xt{t|amb-\\x94b>k"t f z[ cb|1d<y\\xa0g,&akgkkgms g,&Iebli\\x7fms!ul d\\\',typeof,)|doikgauud#!==vkh}l!,)yxdxbzv`tm,(|fY\\x7f~d`hmvr$callxl ,\\\'wzfin\\x7f~m[!c,0K~pyqvb7hkuxynmBd#=== z[ cb|1d<y\\u011eg,(lfi~ah`{ms g,)gk}ejo{\\x7fcms!g,&qnfme|ms"fv!k4}l ,,hbmz}t|gYzrrm!!!k\\xd7,\\\'wd|mbb~l!d"in!v!kI}l!,\\\'wd|mbb~mg,+[`xif~P`aulmd*instanceof!v!k1},(Wybjbyabl"d"inv!k4},+hmab_xp|g{xl"d"inv!k4},+TScghxe\\x7frfpl"d"inv!kP},%Dscafl"d"in,8[xtm}nLzNEGQMKAdGG^NTY\\x1ckl"d"inb< f z[ cb|1d<y\\u02a1g,&qnfme|ms g,)gk}ejo{\\x7fcms!g,&Iebli\\x7fms"l!,)~oih\\x7fgyucmk"t (\\x80,.jjvx|vDgyg}knbl"d"inkfl"v,.jjvx|vDgyg}knbmxl!,)~oih\\x7fgyucgr&Objectn vuq%valuevfq(writable[#c}) %{s#t ,4KJarz}hrjxl@EWCOQDRB,3LKfs{}wsnqB{iAMWBP@,;DCj{}DSKUAWyTK[C[XrHZ^RFZ[[,7HGn\\x7fyxowiES}PGWOW\\\\vL^BN,5JI`}{~iuk{m\\x7fRAQMURxNG,3LKsnsjpl~nB{iAMWBP@,2MLpg\\x7fa}kEnrjl~PQGG,5JI`}{~iuk{m\\x7fTLTVDVWMM,1NMwf|`rjF\\x7fm}qk~TD,4KJert|tripAjNVPBTUCC,4KJpo|ksmyoAjNVPBTUCC[+s#,)Vyn`h`fe|,,olbcCt~vz|cz,6ID}u\\x7fuuhs@ieg|v@EHZMOY[#s$l$*%s%l%u&k4s&l$l&ms\\\'l l\\\'mk"t j\\x06l#*%s%l%u&k?s&l#l&ms\\\'l ,(lfi~ah`{ml\\\'mk"t j\\ufffbl ,(lfi~ah`{m*%s%l%u&kls&l&vr%matchxgr&RegExp$*\\\\$[a-z]dc_$ n"[!cvk:}l ,(lfi~ah`{ml&m,&efkaoTmk"t j\\uffcef z[ cb|1d<y\\u024fg,&qnfme|ms gr&RegExp$+constructor$!in"vr$testxl ,+CX@BJ|t\\x7fvzam[!cv!k\\xb2}yZl vr(toStringx[ c,AzMAN@ES\\x08zKMM_G}U\\\\]GQ{YCQ_SX]IWP.\\x1cd#=== l ,&ufnhxbm!v!kd}ugr&safarid\\\',typeof,)|doikgauud#!==vk=}gr&safari,0`da{Zzb~~pyzhtqqm&k\\u010e(=l v,,c}kaTpfrvtermxzzzz[$c}) %{s!t (\\x85l ,.}jcb{|zFbxjx}~mvr\\\'setItemx,+xc`kDuhZvfp, ["c}l ,.}jcb{|zFbxjx}~mvr*removeItemx,+xc`kDuhZvfp[!c}) \\x7f{s!l!,$gjbbmgr,DOMException,2CF[AWH]AY^YY[[\\x7fdpqmd#===vkC}l ,.}jcb{|zFbxjx}~m,&jbfn~cm0d#===k"t f fv!k>}g,(lfi~ah`{m,,hbmz}t|gYzrrm!!k`l ,)`doiukkTSm!vkJ}l ,,\\\\bgadt`Vbpxcmv!k4}l ,.C\\\\@~{}`pdRn|tomk"t f z[ cb|1d<y\\u0165g,(lfi~ah`{ms g,)gk}ejo{\\x7fcms!,(|fY\\x7f~d`hs",\\\'nfmosCks#fv!k4}l ,,hbmz}t|gYzrrm!!!k\\u0113l v,-n|jqewVxp{rvmmx,&eff\\x7fkx[!cs$l$,)}eOmyoZB]mvl"mx[ cv,\\\'umyfjohmxgr&RegExp$#\\\\s*$!gn"$ ["cvl#mx,*djxdxjs~vv[!c0b<v!kh}l!l"mvl"mx[ cvr\\\'replacexgr&RegExp$#\\\\s*$!gn"$ ["cvl#mx,*djxdxjs~vv[!c0b<v!kP}l!,\\\'wd|mbb~mvl"mx[ c,4Ozt}}zn;LqkxIOcQVD_zd#!== f z[ cb|1d<1b|\'', '0fea6a13c52b4d4725368f24b045ca84': {}, 'aa59d67c2123f094d0d6798ffe651c4d': {}}, 'buildId': '1.0.1.1363', 'assetPrefix': '//s16.tiktokcdn.com/tiktok/falcon', 'isFallback': False, 'customServer': True}
```

I can reach any values by writing so:

```
    import json
    parsed = json.loads(source_code)
    props = parsed['props']['pageProps']['videoData']
    follower = props['authorStats']['followerCount']
    heartcount = props['authorStats']['heartCount']
    AuthorID = props['itemInfos']['authorId']
    Commentcount = pandas.DataFrame(props['itemInfos']['commentCount']
    CreateTime = props['itemInfos']['createTime']
```

But I was not able to put all of them into a dataframe with one row and all of those follower,heartcount etc as columns.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: kindly post ur expected output dataframe

Comment: Hi Sammy thanks for your help. The Expected Output as a dataframe with   columns :follower , heartcount,AuthorID,Commentcount,createTime as headers for columns and a row which includes information about those columns. Such as   1332331 (for followers), 16613(heartcount) etc